# Working with different Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables `tbl_client` and `tbl_branch` linked with the `client_id`.  I have created a `ClientController`  and a `BranchController`.

Now I need to control the branch under client view. I have and `ActionLink`

```
     <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.client_id}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  id=item.client_id}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", new {  id=item.client_id})
        @Html.ActionLink("Branch Management","BranchController", new {id = item.client_id},null)
     </td>
```

in the client view which should handle all branches of the selected client.

Now what I need is

When the `Branch Management` of a specific client is clicked, I need the filtered branches of the client and - after creating/editing a new branch of a client - the page should redirect to the  same client List

Comment: What is your action name in Branch controller?

Comment: The Action Name is Index in Branch Controller  but when I click this Action Branch Management The selected client_id should filter the list of the branches that are part of client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Branch Management link like this, You need to specify the action name and also  controller name ('Branch') not the whole name ('BranchController')

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Branch Management", 
                     "Index", 
                     "Branch", new {id = item.client_id},null)
```

This will redirect you to Index view in branch controller, where you should filter the list of branches according client id and return the view.

you should have your action result similar to this

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
      List<Branch> model = populateFromDB();
      return View(model);
}
```

Also an Index view typed with `@model namespace.List<Branch>`

Comment: Thanx for the reply . How Can I list out the branches which are according to the client ?

Comment: Thanx it worked .. I was wondering if you suggest me with another  answer. With the filtered table when I add / edit Branch Information after submitting the form I need to regain the filtered view of the site according to the client.